# How to get an ip addres of portikuar web site in python

Tags: python

i need to get ip for any web site in terminal

i utiluse recvest leabry in python
i tried to pass web site name to my program
import requests

x = requests.get('Google')

print(x.text)

Comment: `socket.gethostbyname("www.google.com")`

Comment: `requests` is a library for making HTTP requests. If your goal is to convert a URL into an IP address, what you want is called *DNS resolution*, not an HTTP request. And AKX's comment will help with that. However, no program is going to automatically convert a vaguely worded string name like "Google" into an IP address magically. You need a URL or something recognizable by some Internet protocol.

Comment: If you "need to get [the] ip for any web site in terminal" then that has nothing to do with Python. The universal CLI utility for that is `nslookup`. If you _do_ specifically need to know how to do this in Python, then that has nothing to do with the terminal, so either way, please [edit] your post to [explain what you need](/help/how-to-ask) as well as what you already searched for and how that didn't work for you (because searching _will_ have found you lots of webpages and SO questions about this).

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket
print(socket.getaddrinfo('google.com', 80))
```

now you only have to choose if you want to have ipv4 or v6